# Problems login ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, login, ubuntu-10.10

I recently change my compiz settings for my cube and upon restarting my pc it first black screened, where it got stuck, on this screen the last command stated that it was checking the battery status, it was like this for hours i finally got thru to the Login screen but it will not accept the password (with i know is correct).
I am a novice with Ubuntu but have read and tried everything the forums have told me to do  but to no avail.... Please, please, please any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks.